# TextView получение getLineCount()

Tags: android

Если `TextView` находится в `LinearLayout` то количество линий получаю

```
    final TextView textView = (TextViewPlus)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("МНОГО ТЕКСТА");

    final ViewTreeObserver vto = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            final ViewTreeObserver obs = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            Log.d("TEST", "lines=" + textView.getLineCount());
        }
    });
```

Но если `TextView` находится в `RelativeLayout` как не мучаюсь не удается получить количество строк. В чем проблема?

Объекты получаю во фрагменте в методе

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: И что пишет? 0 линий?

Comment: Если TextView находится в LinearLayout, то получаю число строк, а если TextView находится в RelativeLayout, то результат всегда 0

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вешать `addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` не на TextView а на главный лаяут в активити.

Comment: На самый главный Layout или на тот в котором находится TextView?

Comment: Лучше на корневой лаяут вашей активити